Activate Defender for cloud on storage account level
i try to activate defender on storage account level by policy
i use this article to find the value : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-storage-infrastructure-as-code-enablement?tabs=enable-storage-account
i write this
Policy Definition :
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "DFC",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "Effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Policy Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "Audit",
          "DeployIfNotExists",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Security/DefenderForStorageSettings",
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/fb1c8493-542b-48eb-b624-b4c8fea62acd"
          ],
          "deployment": {
            "properties": {
              "mode": "incremental",
              "template": {
                "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "resources": [
                  {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Security/DefenderForStorageSettings",
                    "apiVersion": "2022-12-01-preview",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/current')]",
                    "properties": {
                      "isEnabled": true,
                      "malwareScanning": {
                        "onUpload": {
                          "isEnabled": true,
                          "capGBPerMonth": 5000
                        }
                      },
                      "sensitiveDataDiscovery": {
                        "isEnabled": true
                      },
                      "overrideSubscriptionLevelSettings": true
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "parameters": {
                "storageAccountName": {
                  "value": "[field('name')]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "versions": [
      "1.0.0"
    ]
  }
  }
}

but it doesn't work
can you help me to do it working
try yo do it working

I think your role definition is wrong.
It should be Owner 8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635 instead of Security Admin.
"roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
          ],

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-storage-introduction#availability
